# Get altitude value from WMS

Tags: qgis, wms, dem, altitude

If I load a WMS service into QGIS I could query with the selection tool for every pixel the altitude value. Where does QGIS get this altitude value from? A WMS does not normally have any altitude values.

How could I export this as a pointcloud/mesh/grid? Actually if I export the wms, the altitude is everywhere zero, but as described above QGIS has the altitude so I want use it.

WMS-URL: https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dgm200

Comment: It's a DGM, so obviously it has altitude values, otherwise it wouldn't be a DGM. You can't export WMS layers.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS use an WMS OGC standard called GetFeatureInfo to get feature info values from the WMS. If you in a newer QGIS turn on the Debugging/Development Tools Panel and start logging you can see the request sent to the WMS server. If you copy the GET URL and run it in a browser you will download a QML file with the info as GML. You cannot get the entire map only point info. Many providers also make their WMS available as download but I don't if this is possibly from Geodatenzentrum.

Comment: The download link can be found here:https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/catalog/product/view/id/756/s/digitales-gelandemodell-gitterweite-200-m-dgm200/category/8/?___store=default under 'Direktdownload'